# if exists else query not working sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
If exists
(select @item from Table_RestaurantsTransaction
where Mobile=@mobile and OrderPlaced=0 and Restaurant=@restaurantName ) 

begin

update Table_RestaurantsTransaction
set Quantity+=@quantity
where Item=@item and Mobile=@mobile and OrderPlaced=0 and Restaurant=@restaurantName

end

else

begin

insert into Table_RestaurantsTransaction(Mobile,TransactionID,Item,Price,DecisionStatus,OrderPlaced,TransactionDate,Restaurant,Quantity)
values(@mobile,@transactionID,@item,@price,1,0,GETDATE(),@restaurantName,@quantity)


end
end
```

In the above query, insert query is executed only for the first time when I add the item. Then update query is getting executed if I add the same item. But if I try to add new item, the insert query is not getting executed which is in the else clause.

Kindly tell my mistake.

Comment: According to your exists test, you are not allowing multiple items for each Mobile/OrderPlaced/Restaurant combo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to test for the existence of the item in the `if` clause:

```
If exists (select 1
           from Table_RestaurantsTransaction
           where item = @item and Mobile=@mobile and OrderPlaced=0 and Restaurant=@restaurantName
          ) 
. . .
```

However, you should learn about the `merge` statement which does this all in one statement.